# Problem downloading website with Python Requests.get() method on a AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: python, web-scraping, amazon-ec2, get, python-requests

I have a webscraping project that is stuck.

I am using the Requests package and the get() method to download the website http, after which I want to use Beautiful Soup on it.

It works fine on my labtop, but when I upload the program to my AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance, I run into an error. I have tried other websites, and they all work, I only run into these problems with this site.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Based on the error messages, I suspected SSL issues, but even with the *verify=False* parameter, it still wont work.

The code:

```
import requests
    
url = "http://www.kino.dk"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

The error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 485, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1647, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls12_check_peer_sigalg', 'wrong signature type')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 352, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 491, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls12_check_peer_sigalg', 'wrong signature type')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.kino.dk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls12_check_peer_sigalg', 'wrong signature type')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 239, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.kino.dk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls12_check_peer_sigalg', 'wrong signature type')])")))
```

Comment: It should be `r = requests.get(url, verify=False)` instead of `r = request.get(url, verify=False)` (mind the 's' at the end of `requests`).

Comment: Yeah I am sorry. Typo, it was actually with 's'. The code works great on my labtop, but I am getting an error when I run it from my cloud instance

Comment: @Hinkakan your code looks fine. in case if it's works from a location but from another it's not. so you have to add `User-Agent`, otherwise it's `GEO` location block.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Okay, I tried both adding some browser headings incl. user-agent, tried some free-proxies, and even tried switching to a AWS server closer to home, no luck. Seems like it is a very hardcore anti-scraper they have employed..

Comment: It would seem the site has employed some very effective anti-scraping countermeasures